# Azure WebApp and calling an mTLS protected API

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, mtls

I have an Azure WebApp which needs to make calls to an API which is protected by mTLS (2-way SSL).  I need to understand the following:

1. How do I trust the cert of the API provider?
2. How do I call the API from my code? (i.e. setting up the mTLS connection.)